# Inverse Function Theorem For Function Transforming Polar Coordinates Into Cartesian Coordinates.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, inverse-function-theorem

Let $U=(0,\infty)\times (0,2\pi]$

Define a function $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ by
$$F(r,\theta)= (r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)).$$

Here all $4$ partial derivatives of component functions exist and are continuous. So $F$ is continuously differentiable with non zero Jacobian $r$ at $(r,\theta)$. So  by inverse function theorem, $F$ is locally invertible at every point with **continuously** differentiable inverse. So in particular on the positive part of real axis. But this is **not** true since inverse function is not continuous on the positive part of real axis.

So my Question is : what am I missing here ?

Comment: To apply the inverse function theorem you need to pick a point in $U^\circ$.

Comment: @copper.hat  Thank you .

Comment: In this particular case it can be 'fixed' since you can extend $F$ to $(0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$. So, there is always a local inverse.